# ID of non checked checkbox's

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How could I get the ids of the unchecked checkboxes?

I have the code below but I seem to be getting a single value in the array that is being used for `state`

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
                 if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
                 {
                    checkbox.push($(this).data("id"));
                    state = 1;
                 }else{
                    $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
                    checkbox.push($(this).data("id"));
                    state = 0;
                 }
```

Comment: `state` doesn’t *look* like an array…

Comment: @minitech Its set further up the document I want an array of 0 and 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not` to get unchecked ones.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").not(':checked').each(function(){
     checkbox.push($(this).data("id"));
});
```

One issue could be you are doing

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', false);
```

in your else condition so probably if your first element goes to else it will result in setting all to unchecked (if `attr` works fine enough).

If you want an array of 0..1

```
var checkbox=[], state=[]; 
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function () {
    var flg = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
    checkbox.push($(this).data("id"));
    state.push(flg);
});
```

Comment: `input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)`?

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of unchecked checkboxes

```
var uncheckedIds = $("input[type='checkbox']").not(':checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).data('id');
}).get();
```